# are there any other shells than bash/dash which are used used as default in GNU/Linux distros?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, dash, distributions

Debian/Ubuntu use bash/dash and while you can use and have access to other shells, they don't work well with the kernel, so for booting up purposes, you have to have bash/dash. Are there any other shells which have been given the privileges that bash/dash has been given that there is a plethora of them around?

Also is there a feature that dash or bash has that make them the king of shells or not? I do know that bash, at least, is considered fat or bloatware a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bash`/`dash` are not predominant because of any special interaction with the kernel. The reason for their predominance over other options (e.g. `csh` variants such as `tcsh`, or other things like `zsh`) is just that both are `sh`-compatible, and the vast majority of shell scripts are written for that target. There's nothing that requires either `bash` or `dash` specifically; it's quite possible, for example, to make a distro based on Busybox that uses its `ash`, even for scripting purposes, and there are also distros which make `zsh` the default shell for interactive use even while retaining a different one as `/bin/sh`.

As regards "the king of shells", there's nothing too special here, I don't believe; it's just compatibility. This and the fact that `bash` is the GNU Project shell, and so gains some cachet by association.